# My cat is afraid of me and plays aggressively

Tags: cats, medicines, diseases, fear

I recently adopted a 1 and a half month old cat.

He was very calm and friendly when I first brought him home and he would sleep on everyone's lap.
So I took him to the vet to get him checked and make sure he's OK.
The vet diagnosed him with a disease which he said was from the cat's mother.
So I had to apply an eye drop to his eyes every six hours or he could lose his eyes.
He didn't like it at all. I had to force him to sit stable so I could apply the eye drop.

Since then, he is almost always afraid of people and me(unless he's sleepy), he never sits on my lap, never purrs and plays really aggressively and bites and scratches. When someone is approaching him, he puffs his tail and runs away(most of the time).

He's now at 2 and a half months old.
So my question here is, is he ever going to go back normal and show some affection and be nice, or will he remain this way? Should I re-home him or is he scared of all people?
What should I do to make him trust me again?
What should I avoid doing?

Thank you and sorry for the length of this question.